# How to prevent text clipping when listview divider height is negative?

Tags: java, android, listview

I'm trying to reduce the spacing of the items in my listview by setting the divider height to a negative value. But the problem is after some value, about -20dp, texts start getting clipped.

I already tried to set the background of each item to transparent but with no luck.

Thanks.

Comment: any reason for giving devider height in negative

Comment: To adjust (reduce) list items? Why? Is there other technique do so? Thanks.

Comment: ...how about using a different layout for your list items that has less height?

Comment: I can't. I'm on different situation from what you are thinking. Further, I am actually allowing the user to adjust the spacing via a slider.